# Write a function that takes an array of objects and an object with properties & values

Tags: javascript, jquery

Write a function that takes an array of objects and an object with properties and values.  The function will return an array of objects where the prop/vals match.

I know the following, but am having a lot of trouble understanding the question itself. Any help is appreciated!

An example return would be :

```
thinglist = [
{age: 'four', type: 'Cat', name: 'mammal'},
{age: 'six', type: 'Dog', name: 'mammal'},
{age: 'seven', type: 'Dog', name: 'mammal'},
{age: 'two', type: 'Lizard', name: 'reptile'}
]


withVals( thingList , {type: 'Dog', name: 'mammal'} )
=> [
{age: 'seven', type: 'Dog', name: 'mammal'},
{age: 'six', type: 'Dog', name: 'mammal'}
]
```

I know how to iterate over the array and pull out the values, but I have no idea how to pass in an object to the function as well. Then iterate over it to see if those values match.

This is how I see it starting:

```
function withPropValues(arr, obj) {
    var newArray = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        if (arr[i] === obj) {
            newArray.push(arr[i])
        }
    }
    return newArray;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to loop over all the properties of `object` and see if they match the same-named properties of each item in `array`. You can get all the property names with `Object.keys(object)`, and from there it's a matter of accessing the values with bracket notation, e.g., `object[key] === array[i][key]`.

Generally, what you're trying to do could be accomplished very neatly with `filter`, and you could match all properties with an `every` over `Object.keys`:

```
function withVals(array, object) {
    var keys = Object.keys(object);
    return array.filter(function(item) {
        return keys.every(function(k) { return item[k] === object[k]; });
    });
}
```

- `filter` takes a callback which examines an item from the array and returns `true` if the item should be kept or `false` if it should not be kept. It returns a new filtered array.
- `every` takes a callback that examines an item of an array and returns either `true` or `false`. If each item in the array causes the function to return `true`, then the `every` call also returns `true`, but a single `false` value causes it to return `false`.
- The `Object.keys(object).every` is testing if *every* key of `object` has a value that matches the corresponding property value in some item of `array`. If so, include that item in the filtered version of the array.

Answer (score 0):

```
var thingList = [
    {age: 'four', type: 'Cat', name: 'mammal'},
    {age: 'six', type: 'Dog', name: 'mammal'},
    {age: 'seven', type: 'Dog', name: 'mammal'},
    {age: 'two', type: 'Lizard', name: 'reptile'}
    ];
    withPropValues(thingList, {type: 'Cat', name: 'mammal'})
    function withPropValues(arr, obj) 
    {
    var newArray = [],
        sum = 0;
    for(var c in obj)
    {
        sum++;
    }
    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) 
    {
        var match=0;
        for(var prop in arr[i])
        {
            for(c in obj)
            {
                if(obj[c] == arr[i][prop])
                {
                    match++;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if(match == sum) 
            {
                newArray.push(arr[i]);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return newArray;
}
```